# How can I tell Meson that a cmake subproject shall generate position-independent code (PIC)?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, meson-build, position-independent-code

I have a Meson project for a shared library. It uses a CMake subproject, which supplies a static library:

```
cmake = import('cmake')
sub_prj = cmake_subproject('some_subproject-1.0.0')
sub_dep = sub_prj.dependency('static_sublib')
...
my_lib = library('my_lib', ..., dependencies : sub_dep)
```

Meson gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Can't link non-PIC static library 'cm_gsl' into shared library 'toolbox'. Use the 'pic' option to static_library to build with PIC.
```

How can I tell the CMake module that the static library must have position independent code?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible using the following code:

```
cmake = import('cmake')
cmake_opts = cmake.subproject_options()
cmake_opts.add_cmake_defines({'CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE': true})
sub_proj = cmake.subproject('projectname', options: cmake_opts)
my_lib = sub_proj.dependency('lib-target')
```

The documentation for the configuration options for CMake subprojects can be found here: https://mesonbuild.com/CMake-module.html#configuration-options

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for me. Meson still thinks the code is position dependent even though the option setting does work and the object file is position independent.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/10764) for reference.